# javascript Error: Permission denied to access property 'u8'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a legacy jsp page which has button element . i am using frameset/frames. on click of this button function parent.u8()  is called.
But as soon as i click on button,i get below error

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'u8'
parent.u8()
```

Its a big jsp. so i dont want to paste complete content here. I tried to take the bare minimum html markup from server generated html page
and created the html page with similar structure it works fine there.But not in real application.

Just for information there is one iframe elemet also but that is lying altogether in separate frame not in the frame where button exists(so possiblity something related to iframe looks bleak to me).
u8 function lies inside top head Tag. **Folks i know its tough to tell what can be exact reason without actual markup but probably you can help
me regarding the possible reasons when can i get  this kind of excpetion Permission denied to access property**

**Update:-**

This was working before. Issue began when i started using tinymce(WYSIWYG) editor in one of the frame.Tinymce created one iframe element  but that is loaded from appserver only. Pasting  below the code generated inside body of one of the frame. May be it helps

```
<span id="bodyTest_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin" role="application" aria-labelledby="bodyTest_voice">
<span id="bodyTest_voice" class="mceVoiceLabel" style="display:none;">Rich Text Area</span>
<table id="bodyTest_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; height: 323px;">
<tbody>
<tr class="mceFirst mceLast">
<td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
<iframe id="bodyTest_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 323px; display: block;">
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('bodyTest').onLoad.dispatch();" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">
<p>
<span color="blue" data-mce-style="color: blue;" style="color: blue;">
<strong>adain</strong>
</span>
```

Comment: Is the page loaded into the frame from the same domain as the top page?

Comment: Has to be same domain (**exactly** the same), same scheme ("http" or "https"), and same port number.

Comment: Its eaxctly same.i verified it from net tab under firebug.

Comment: Pointy i did one update to OP. May be it helps to convey some information

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by the frames existing on different origins (e.g. domains). JavaScript is not allowed to access data from different origins for security reasons.

Comment: Quentin i did one update to OP. May be it helps to convey some information